# Проблема с таблицей HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица. Нужно вставить `Input box`, только к определенным тегам `td`.

Как правильно описать условие?

```
$(function()    {
$('td').click(function(e)   {
    //ловим элемент, по которому кликнули
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement;
    //получаем название тега
    var elm_name = t.tagName.toLowerCase();
    //если это инпут - ничего не делаем
    if(elm_name == 'input') {return false;}
    var val = $(this).html();
    var code = '<input type=text id=\"edit\" value='+val+' />';
    $(this).empty().append(code);
    $('#edit').focus();
    $('#edit').blur(function()  {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().empty().html(val);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Решил проблему:
`$(function()    {
$('td` **.имя_класса** `').click(function(e)`

Comment: вообще,так-на будущее- посмотрите angularjs-там это можно сделать буквально одной строчкой...

Comment: @A_Chernitsov оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ